# How to use open service mesh in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, service, consul, istio

I am trying to test open service mesh for our application.

No tags in serverfault for service mesh or servicemesh or osm or open service mesh,etc.
So I kept istio as serverfault tag to this question as it is also a similar product of service mesh.

So, installed the osm cli on my laptop using this [link](https://release-v1-1.docs.openservicemesh.io/docs/guides/cli/)

In my kubernetes (minikube), installed the osm using:

```
osm install
```

This installed osm in the namespace osm-system

[osm pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPSri.png)

Then installed the sample application provided by them using their [documentation](https://release-v1-2.docs.openservicemesh.io/docs/getting_started/install_apps/)

Their bookstore app working fine.

My spec.traffic.enablePermissiveTrafficPolicyMode is still true so no rules required and by default all traffic should be allowed by default.

So for testing, I did try on mondo-express and mongo containers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mongodb-configmap
  namespace: mongosample
data:
  database_url:  mongodb-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: mongosample
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongodb-secret
  namespace: mongosample
type: Opaque
data:
  mongo-root-username:  dXNlcm5hbWU=
  mongo-root-password:  cGFzc3dvcmQ=


##echo -n 'username' | base64
##echo -n 'password' | base64
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  namespace: mongosample
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerhub-secret
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8081
          env:
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-username
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-password
          - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-configmap
                key: database_url
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mongosample
  name: mongodb-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      #nodePort: 30000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  namespace: mongosample
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dockerhub-secret
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo:latest
          ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
          env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-username
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: mongodb-secret
                key: mongo-root-password
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mongosample
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

And without the osm it is working fine.

[no osm pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgHJ8.png)

So, enabled osm for this mongosample namespace using:

```
osm namespace add mongosample
```

After enabling and restarting pods:

[osm enabled pods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dwb4o.png)

And error in logs of mongo-express

[error in mongo-express](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Og8TK.png)

If I remove service mesh to this namespace then works fine.

```
osm namespace remove mongosample
```

Please suggest how to fix that?